# makefiles compilation make error

Tags: makefile

```
tree_t *make_empty_tree();
void insert_tree(tree_t *tree, void *name, char *movie);
void insert_node(node_t **root, node_t *new);
void traverse_tree(tree_t *tree);
static void recursive_traverse(node_t *root);
void *search_tree(tree_t *tree, void *key);
/*static void *recursive_search_tree(node_t *root, void *key);*/
void *node_search(node_t *root, void *key);

tree_t *make_empty_tree(){
    tree_t *tree;
    tree = malloc(sizeof(*tree));
    tree->root = NULL;
    return tree;
}

void insert_tree(tree_t *tree, void *name, char *movie){
    int i = 0, count = 0;
    node_t *new;
    char *c;
    new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
    assert(new!=NULL);
    strcpy(new->name, name);
    for(i=0; i<strlen(movie); i++) {
        if(isalpha(*(movie+i))){
           count++; 
        } else if(*(movie+i) == ' ') {
           count++; 
        }
    }
    c = malloc(count+1);
    for(i=0; i<count; i++) {
        *(c+i) = *(movie+i);    
    }
    *(c+i) = '\0';

    new->movie = malloc(count+1);
    strcpy(new->movie, c);
    free(c);
    new->left = new->right = NULL;
    insert_node(&(tree->root), new);
}


void traverse_tree(tree_t *tree){
    recursive_traverse(tree->root);
}

static void recursive_traverse(node_t *root) {
    if(root){
       recursive_traverse(root->left);
       printf(root->name);               
       printf("\n");
       free(root->name);
       free(root->movie);
       free(root);
       recursive_traverse(root->right);
    }

}

void *search_tree(tree_t *tree, void *key){
       /*return recursive_search_tree(tree->root, key); */
       return node_search(tree->root, key);
}

/*static void *recursive_search_tree(node_t *root, void *key) {
       int outcome;
       static int comparison = 0;
       if(!root) {
         comparison++;  printf("%s---> ", key);
         printf("%d number of comparisions but NOT FOUND\n", comparison);
         comparison = 0;
         return NULL;   
       }
       if ((outcome = strcmp(key, root->name))<0) {
         comparison++;  
         return recursive_search_tree(root->left, key);
       } else if (outcome > 0) {           
         comparison++;
         return recursive_search_tree(root->right, key);
       } else {
         comparison++;  
         printf("%s---> ", key);
         printf("%d number of comparisions\n", comparison);
         comparison = 0;
         return root->movie;
       }
}*/
void *node_search(node_t *root, void *key) {
    node_t** curr = &root;
    int outcome;
    static int comparison = 0;
    while (*curr){
        outcome = strcmp(key, (*curr)->name);
        comparison++;

        if(outcome<0) {
            curr = &(*curr)->left;
        } else {
            if(outcome == 0){
               printf("%s---> ", key);
               printf("%d number of comparisions\n", comparison);   
               comparison=0;
               return (*curr)->movie;
            }
            curr = &(*curr)->right;
        } 

    }

           printf("%s---> ", key);
           printf("%d number of comparisions but NOT FOUND\n", comparison);
           comparison = 0;


    return (*curr);
}

void insert_node(node_t *(*root), node_t *new)
{
    node_t** curr = root;
    while (*curr)
    {
        if (strcmp(new->name, (*curr)->name) < 0) {
            curr = &(*curr)->left;
        } else {
            curr = &(*curr)->right;
        }
    }

    *curr = new;

}
```

i have this treefunction.c

and im trying to make makefile using vi editor on unix

it keeps giving out this message

```
treefunction.c:6: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
treefunction.c:7: error: expected ')' before '*' token
treefunction.c:8: error: expected ')' before '*' token
treefunction.c:9: error: expected ')' before '*' token
treefunction.c:10: error: expected ')' before '*' token
treefunction.c:11: error: expected ')' before '*' token
treefunction.c:13: error: expected ')' before '*' token
treefunction.c:15: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
treefunction.c:22: error: expected ')' before '*' token
```

can anyone help me fix this

it compiles on my machine but on unix it doesn't

i need to able to make makefile to submit my assignment

can anyone help me please thanks

Comment: Where does the `tree_t` type come from?

Comment: it is a tree structure declared in other files

Comment: What other files? They aren't included here. How does the compiler know about them?

Comment: What was the last change you made? (I certainly hope you didn't type all of this in without testing any of it.)